# Crontab script writing just NULL to database

Tags: cron

I'm starting a script every day with a cronjob:

```
0 1 * * * /bin/bash /home/performanceRatio.sh
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

python3 /home/get_weather_data_crn.py && 
python3 /home/pv.py
```

The script is running but writing just NULL to the mysql database:

```
| 2021-02-03 13:00:00 |    48.17 |     11.14 |     NULL |    NULL |     NULL |     NULL | 20          | 1         | CRN    |
| 2021-02-03 14:00:00 |    48.17 |     11.14 |     NULL |    NULL |     NULL |     NULL | 20          | 1         | CRN    |
| 2021-02-03 15:00:00 |    48.17 |     11.14 |     NULL |    NULL |     NULL |     NULL | 20          | 1         | CRN    |
| 2021-02-03 16:00:00 |    48.17 |     11.14 |     NULL |    NULL |     NULL |     NULL | 20          | 1         | CRN
```

It is getting data from CAMS (a weather service). When starting the script manually it works as it should. The database connection seems to work, it's just not writing the weather values as expected when run with Cron. The other values are written.

Using: Ubuntu 20.04

It's written to the db with:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}/{}'.format(user, passwd, host, database))
df.to_sql(con=engine, name=name, if_exists='append', index = True, chunksize=1000)
```

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it? It is possible the version affects the answer.

Comment: It may be related to the user that is running the script when it's triggered by crontab. This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475694/how-to-specify-in-crontab-by-what-user-to-run-script

Comment: @David I wrote the ubuntu Version. It's 20.04

Comment: @Katu The script is run by the root user I guess,  I'm editing the crontab -e file within the root shell (sudo -s) and didn't specify anything else. How would I check this?

Comment: Can you try this using ./etc/crontab and the user you use? Next: please do not put scripts in /home/, There should only be directories there than point to USERS. Lets assume you could delete a user pv.py your script is gone.

Comment: @whyme In that case, forget my comment. Is happend to me that the script works because I run it with my user and then it doesn't with crontab because is run by the root user. This doesn't seem to be your problem.

Comment: Just writing `./etc/crontab` gave me "no such file or directory". Yea, I got no idea about user handling on Linux.

Comment: And I'm just wondering, that everything EXCEPT these specific values is written to the database. So I guess it's not a problem with permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to be a problem with my paths. I edited crontab -e like this and it worked on a every minute schedule (So it will at 1am too, I guess):

```
0 1 * * * cd /home && /bin/bash /home/performanceRatio.sh
```